# Python - run different function depending on input from user

Tags: python, user-input

I'm creating a program in Python, that will perform two different tasks depending on what user will input. If the user will input name of a text file to be opened, function#1 will be executed, but if user will input a sentence (in a form of a string), then function#2 will be executed.

The only thing I could think of is doing a `try: except:`, where a function will try to open a file, and if it fails, it will assume that user entered a sentence. However this is not the best way, since user could try to open a file that doesn't not exist, which will move to the `except` and  treat the name of the file as a sentence.

```
def main:
    input_x = input("Enter name of the file or type in your sentence")
    try:
        list_y = open(list_x, "r")
        functionOne(list_y)
    except:
        functionTwo(input_x)
```

So if user types in something like myTextFile.txt , then functionOne should be executed, but if the input is "This is a sentence", then functionTwo should be executed.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: This is really vague. Sentence can be a file name almost always... Otherwise, you can require an extension to be entered. Then just have a list of file types and ensure that string ends in "." + extension.

Comment: How do you diffrentiate between a file that doesn't exist and a sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Use `os.path.isfile`:

```
if os.path.isfile(input_x):
    functionOne(open(input_x))
else:
    functionTwo(input_x)
```

Also you might want to use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Answer (score -1):

Function pointers are really simple to use. Try this:

```
def function_one(list):
    pass

def function_one(list):
    pass

function_dict = {'myTextFile.txt': function_one, 
    'This is a sentence': function_two }

user_input = input("Enter name of the file or type in your sentence")

function_dict[user_input]()
```